# "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'" when dividing fields from Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to calculate how much progress a user has made towards their monetary goal they set inside a Django model, but it keeps giving me this error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`

This is how I'm trying to calculate the user's progress:

```
def calculateGoalPercentage(self):
    onePercent = self.goal / 100
    goalPercentage = self.calculateBalance() / onePercent

    return goalPercentage
```

This is my model:

```
class Space(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="New Space")

    balance = models.FloatField(default=0.00)
    goal = models.FloatField(default=100.00, validators=[MinValueValidator(1.00)])

    typeChoices = [
        (0, "Private"),
        (1, "Shared"),
    ]
    space_type = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=typeChoices, null=True, blank=True)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    records = models.ManyToManyField(Record, blank=True, default=None)

    notes = models.TextField(default="")
    
    def calculateBalance(self):
        total = 0

        for record in self.records.all():
            total += record.amount

        return total

    def calculateGoalPercentage(self):
        onePercent = self.goal / 100
        goalPercentage = self.calculateBalance() / onePercent

        return goalPercentage

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the `Record` model:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    memo = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="-")

    def __str__(self):
        name = "Record on " + str(self.added)
        return name
    
    def getName(self):
        name = "Record on " + str(self.added)
        return name
```

Does anyone know what's going on? This seems like an error I would find back when I was a beginner, so I think I'm missing a small detail.

Comment: Could you also include your `Record` model ?

Comment: i added it just now

Comment: What line/statement is triggering the exception? You have two division statements there, the traceback should show which one is at fault. I don't see anything yet that would lead to that error, but you can at least narrow down which one is the trigger.

Comment: Also, are you seeing this on a model instance loaded from the database or from one you're creating in memory prior to saving? If your `goal` field is a string this is the error I'd expect; perhaps you're building an instance based on request data and didn't parse a `request.GET` or `request.POST` value from a string into a float before assigning it to `.goal`?

Comment: As @PeterDeGlopper mentioned your goal value is a string. Troubleshoot the issue by looking at the value being used as goal. Before the line; ```onePercent = self.goal / 100``` put two prints; ```print(self.goal)``` and ```print(type(self.goal))```. The 1st print will print the value and the 2nd print will be the value data type, which is going to be a ```str```. You might be able to get away by just setting the value to a float before dividing; ```float(self.goal)```, but you would rather want to solve the root value issue if you are not expecting a string.

Comment: The error is clear: `self.goal` is a string.  You haven't shown us enough code to explain _why_ that is.  Start by showing us the full error traceback, not just the final error message.

Answer (score 0):

**self.goal** render **string**.But in models it is **float field**.So, just change **self.goal** to **float field.**

```
def calculateGoalPercentage(self):
    goal_value = float(self.goal)
    onePercent = goal_value / 100
    goalPercentage = self.calculateBalance() / onePercent
    return goalPercentage
```

Comment: Now I get this error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Save money'`

Comment: One thing you have to ensure that you have specify goal field as Floatfield but taking string input.If you really want to input both float and sometimes as string field.You should change it to CharField.Just give a try.